# Starting an axis2 service programmatically

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I'm programmatically starting a service in Axis 2 (1.5), like this:

```
ConfigurationContext context = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(null, null);

AxisConfiguration cfg = context.getAxisConfiguration();
Map<String, MessageReceiver> mrMap = new HashMap<String, MessageReceiver>();
mrMap.put("http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only", RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.class.newInstance());
mrMap.put("http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out", RPCMessageReceiver.class.newInstance());

AxisService service = AxisService.createService(MonitorWebService.class.getName(), cfg, mrMap, "", "http://samples", MonitorWebService.class.getClassLoader());
service.setScope("application");
cfg.addService(service);
SimpleHTTPServer server = new SimpleHTTPServer(context, 8080);
server.start();
```

With this set up, the service is only created when the first operation request arrives - how can I force axis to construct the service immediately?

**Update:** I've tried using deployService(), rather than cfg.addService(), and this starts the service up immediately. However, another instance of the service is created when the first request comes in, so that's no good either.

Comment: With this approach could I use service.xml to configure the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cheesy way to do it would be to have the code call the service immediately after you start the service.

Comment: yes, that would be cheesy :) Assuming no other options appear, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can let one of your services implement org.apache.axis2.engine.ServiceLifeCycle. It seems you also need to announce that in the services.xml configuration, like that

```
<service name="MyService" scope="application" class="com.example.MyService">
...
</service>
```

where com.example.MyService is the class implementing ServiceLifeCycle. This class will be notified on service deployment, which usually takes place on container startup. You can hook your code to start other services (programatically) there.