# Deploy a class instance as a web service

Tags: java, web-services

I need to programmatically register a specific instance of an interface as a web service. (The reason is that its a dynamically generated implementation using proxies.)

Something like the following:

`public <T, U extends T> void registerWebService(U implementation, Class<T> interfaceType);`

related question here
[Starting an axis2 service programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491438/starting-an-axis2-service-programmatically)

Comment: The web service should be handled by an embedded HttpServer. (SimpleHttpServer, Jetty, Tomcat, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

(Feel free to edit, the answer is not complete:)

One way forward may be to use Axis' XFireExporter

```
public <T, U extends T> void registerWebService(U implementation, Class<T> interfaceType) {
        XFire xfire = XFireFactory.newInstance().getXFire();
        XFireExporter e = new XFireExporter();
        e.setXfire(xfire);
        e.setServiceInterface(interfaceType);
        e.setServiceBean(implementation);
        e.afterPropertiesSet();
        e.getServiceBean();
//TODO: register with a WebApplicationContext somehow.
}
```

Comment: Hi Hugo, were you able to find a complete solution how to do that? I'd like to achieve something similar. Thanks, Viktor